# Cannot locate .XML file when running .Net Core application via Docker

Tags: .net, docker, swagger

When running a .Net Core API (v2.2) with Docker, it is unable to locate the .XML file for swagger and crashes when trying to access it on localhost, with the following error:

`FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/app/Account.API.XML'.`

On inspecting the container, I can see that this file exists in the directory, but I am unsure why it can't detect it. Here is the contents of my container:

```
root@538b7c4e4b45:/app# ls 
Account.API.deps.json Account.API.pdb Account.API.xml     Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll  appsettings.Development.json web.config Account.API.dll        Account.API.runtimeconfig.json Microsoft.OpenApi.dll  Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.dll            appsettings.json
```

Here is the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
# Create a release executable of the service
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS builder
WORKDIR /build
COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet publish Account.API/Account.API.csproj --framework netcoreapp2.2 --configuration Release --output /release

# Run the executable with .Net Core runtime
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime

ARG ENV_NAME
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$ENV_NAME
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /release ./
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Account.API.dll"]
```

The documentation is registered as follows:

```
  services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Account API", Version = "v1" });

                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

                c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
            });
```

However, outside of Docker, if I create a release with the same options in my Dockerfile, and then run the .dll locally, it is able to find the .XML file it needs and runs as expected.

Any thoughts as to why this might be? 
Any ideas would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

SOLVED - as the docker container is running on linux, and files are case insensitive, I had to change the following line in program.cs: 
`var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.XML"` to `var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"` with lowercase 'xml'.

Comment: You just saved me from what I am pretty sure would be quite a few hours of debugging, thank you.

Comment: Spent a few hours on this. Thanks!